# Raspberrry Pi 3 + Windows IOT Core crashes after some time

Tags: iot, sd-card, windows-10-iot-core

Im developing an uwp app on Raspberry Pi 3 with Windows IOT Core. But after I deploy my app and use it for couple days the os crashes. It says something went wrong. It says "Your pc ran into a problem and needs to restart". It restarts couple times but still same error on every boot.

I tried to remove the sd card(Class 10,64 GB) format it and reinstall everything. At first it was okay but after some time same error appears.
I tried to use different os builds and it didnt work.
I tried to use industrial power supply (5V3A) and  also it didnt work.

My SD Card is not one of the recommended ones but do I really have to get the recommended sd cards to use the windows iot core properly?

Comment: The SD card is likely not the issue, if the device runs fine for days without issue.  If you like, you can try to place the OS on a USB thumb drive and configure the Pi to boot to thumb drives, if you have a thumb drive that works for this.  Sorry I can't be of more help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Your PC ran into a problem and needs to restart" is a typical blue screen message seen on Windows systems from the last few years - laptops and desktops with far larger hard drives and no SD card. The error is not associated with a RAM or disk space shortage (operating systems running in graphical mode usually monitor and actively warn about either). In your case, it is showing at startup, when not much is running (taking up RAM), and you can check the amount of space used on the card with the PC.

The key stats for SD cards are size (you have plenty) and speed (clearly enough or you would have trouble installing/running anything after starting the Pi). The cause is something else, and finding out what will require getting a more detailed error message from Windows - "a problem" could mean anything. In my experience, blue screen errors have mostly involved having a wrong driver installed, sometimes a bad Windows update - but IoT Core has its own alternatives, like ["bad system configuration"](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/94238/blue-screen-due-windows-iot-core-10-b-loading). Look for the underscored string (e.g., BAD_SYSTEM_CONFIG_INFO) at the end of your blue screen message, as that is the first hint.

Unfortunately, most Windows BSoD documentation is for traditional PCs, so I cannot recommend specific troubleshooting tools and be sure that they will run on the Pi.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Windows Debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/manage-your-device/windowsdebugger) to debug the kernel and drivers on Windows IoT Core. WinDbg is a very powerful debugger that most Windows developers are familiar with. Or you can also refer to this [topic](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d102e06a-89af-4705-8099-f1dcdaf344ad/crash-dump?forum=WindowsIoT) in MSDN, it shows how to create the dump file when the app crashes. If possible, you can share your code so that we can reproduce the issue.